# Нужна ли запятая после "поистине"?

Tags: пунктуация

Поистине, тот, кто не ценит жизнь, её не заслуживает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Да, здесь в значении вводного слова, поэтому обособляется.

> ПОИСТИНЕ, нареч. Действительно, в самом деле. П. странный случай. П.
>   очаровательные места. Быть п. хозяином положения. <Поистине, в зн.
>   вводн. сл. Вот уж, поистине, это был праздник!

Кузнецов.
[поистине | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5&all=x)